Do matrix powers preserve the argmax of a quadratic form?
Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive-definite matrix which is such that $M^2 \succeq M$, where $\succeq$ denotes the partial ordering in the space of positive-semidefinite matrices (i.e., $A \succeq B \implies A - B$ is positive semidefinite), and suppose we are given:
$$ v_* \in \underset{v \in \mathcal{S}}{\operatorname{argmax}} v^\top M v$$
where $\mathcal{S}$ is a compact (i.e., closed and bounded) subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Would that imply that the same $v_*$ is a maximizer for the quadratic form with the squared matrix, i.e.:
$$ v_* \in \underset{v \in \mathcal{S}}{\operatorname{argmax}} v^\top M^2 v \quad ?$$
More generally, if the above holds, can that be extended to any positive power of $M$?
Attempt:
For $n=1$, the result is trivial, since multiplication by a positive constant does not affect the argmax. For any $n\geq 1$, we know that $v^\top M^2 v \geq v^\top M v$, for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, given the assumption above that $M^2 \succeq M$. As a maximizer, it also holds that $v_*^\top M v_* - v^\top M v \geq 0$, for all $v \in \mathcal{S}$. We could assume that $M$ is a diagonal matrix, since any positive-definite matrix has a spectral decomposition, and we could operate in the space spanned by its eigenvectors. In that case, we have $v_*^\top M v_* - v^\top M v = \sum_{i=1}^n m_{ii}(v_{*,i}^2 - v_i^2) \geq 0$. However, that doesn't necessarily help much with $\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ii}^2(v_{*,i}^2 - v_i^2)$, since the individual terms $v_{*,i}^2 - v_i^2$ could be positive or negative (if they were all non-negative, we could say $\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ii}^2(v_{*,i}^2 - v_i^2) \geq \min_{j\leq n} m_{jj}\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ii}(v_{*,i}^2 - v_i^2) \geq 0$, since $m_{ii} > 0$, for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$). Lastly, also note that $\mathcal{S}$ is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but only a compact subset within it.

Have you tried diagonalizing $M$ by a congruence transformation? The argmax will then be the span of the basis vectors corresponding to the largest diagonal entries. The largest diagonal entries stay the largest when you take the matrix to a positive power.

I forgot to say: by an orthogonal congruence transformation, I.e. using the spectral theorem.

@darijgrinberg, thanks for your comment, yes, I've tried diagonalizing it via the spectral theorem, as explained in the paragraph about my attempt, but even then it was not clear to me that the argmax would be preserved. I'm not sure if I understood your comment 100%, though.

The maximiser in general is not preserved. E.g. when $M=\operatorname{diag}(2,1)$ and $S={x=(2,1)^T,,y=(1,3)^T}$, we have $\arg\max_{v\in S}v^TMv=y$ but $\arg\max_{v\in S}v^TM^2v=x$.

Thanks @user1551. So it seems that the argmax wouldn't be preserved in the general case. Do you know what kind of additional structure/assumptions on the set $\mathcal{S}$ could make a difference?

Sorry, I don't know any useful condition, except the one that everyone knows, namely, that $S$ is a closed ball centred at the origin.

Oh! Sorry, I thought it was a ball for some reason (probably because it is a ball in the standard Rayleigh ratio problems).
